# A question on an argument in Woronowicz’s paper on the compact quantum group $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $ q \in [0,1) $. The compact quantum group $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $ is defined to be the universal unital $ C^{*} $-algebra that is generated by two elements $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ satisfying the following five relations:
\begin{align}
\alpha^{*} \alpha + \beta^{*} \beta       & = 1, \\
\alpha \alpha^{*} + q^{2} \beta \beta^{*} & = 1, \\
\beta^{*} \beta                           & = \beta \beta^{*}, \\
\alpha \beta                              & = q \beta \alpha, \\
\alpha \beta^{*}                          & = q \beta^{*} \alpha.
\end{align}
In his paper [*Twisted $ \text{SU}(2) $ Group. An Example of a Non-Commutative Differential Calculus*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ems-ph.org%2Fjournals%2Fshow_pdf.php%3Fissn%3D0034-5318%26vol%3D23%26iss%3D1%26rank%3D5&ei=NZWTVcOoBM71oASw_ILoCg&usg=AFQjCNE7msZDaxPfyjZWHn7ajMPtH6ILag&sig2=KWZzMsTHNwfzdhb5qtZ_qQ&bvm=bv.96952980,d.cGU), Woronowicz proves that there is a $ * $-isomorphism between $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $ and $ {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) $. Part of his proof proceeds as follows. He begins with the claim that
\begin{align}
  \sigma(\alpha^{*} \alpha)
& \subseteq \left\{ 0,1 - q^{2},1 - q^{4},1 - q^{6},\ldots,1 \right\} ~ \text{and} \\
  \sigma(\beta^{*} \beta)
& \subseteq \left\{ 0,\ldots,q^{6},q^{4},q^{2},1 \right\}.
\end{align}
Next, he chooses arbitrary continuous functions $ f,g: [0,1] \to \Bbb{R} $ such that:

- $ f(0) = 0 $ and $ f(t) = 1 $ for all $ t \in \left[ 1 - q^{2},1 \right] $.
- $ g(1) = 1 $ and $ g(t) = 0 $ for all $ t \in \left[ 0,q^{2} \right] $.

Letting $ a = \alpha ~ f(\alpha^{*} \alpha) $ and $ b = \beta ~ g(\beta^{*} \beta) $, he then says that $ (a,b) $ is a generating pair for $ {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) $, i.e.,
\begin{align}
a^{*} a + b^{*} b & = 1, \\
a a^{*}           & = 1, \\
b^{*} b           & = b b^{*}, \\
a b               & = 0, \\
a b^{*}           & = 0.
\end{align}

The problem is, none of this seems to work. For example, let us try to verify that $ a a^{*} = 1 $. Observe that
\begin{align}
    a a^{*}
& = [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{*} \alpha)] [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{*} \alpha)]^{*} \\
& = [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{*} \alpha)] [f(\alpha^{*} \alpha)^{*} ~ \alpha^{*}] \\
& = [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{*} \alpha)]
    \left[ \overline{f}(\alpha^{*} \alpha) ~ \alpha^{*} \right] \qquad
    (\text{By the continuous functional calculus.}) \\
& = [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{*} \alpha)] [f(\alpha^{*} \alpha) ~ \alpha^{*}] \qquad
    \left( \text{As $ \overline{f} = f $.} \right) \\
& = [f(\alpha \alpha^{*}) ~ \alpha] [\alpha^{*} ~ f(\alpha \alpha^{*})] \qquad
    (\text{As $ \alpha ~ p(\alpha^{*} \alpha) = p(\alpha \alpha^{*}) ~ \alpha $ for every
    polynomial $ p $.}) \\
& = [f(\alpha \alpha^{*})] (\alpha \alpha^{*}) [f(\alpha \alpha^{*})] \\
& = h(\alpha \alpha^{*}),
\end{align}
where $ h: [0,1] \to \Bbb{R} $ is defined by $ h(t) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} t [f(t)]^{2} $ for all $ t \in [0,1] $. However,
$$
\sigma(\alpha \alpha^{*}) \cup \{ 0 \} = \sigma(\alpha^{*} \alpha) \cup \{ 0 \},
$$
so $ h|_{\sigma(\alpha \alpha^{*})} $ is the identity function on $ \sigma(\alpha \alpha^{*}) $, which yields $ h(\alpha \alpha^{*}) = \alpha \alpha^{*} $ instead of $ h(\alpha \alpha^{*}) = 1 $.

> **Question.** For those who are familiar with this topic, am I hallucinating, or is something not right here?

**Note:** Woronowicz’s argument is given on Page 179, in Section A2, of his paper.

Comment: [deleted comment caused by not reading properly; sorry]

Comment: @Yemon: Hi Yemon. You’re alright. I didn’t see your deleted comment anyway. :)

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in the definition of the functions $f$ and $g$? (Not that I'm able to find a correct definition right now...). I did check that the inverses ($\tilde{T}_H^1$ and $\tilde{T}_H^2$) are maps from $SU_0(2)$ to $SU_q(2)$ however (modulo some concerns I have about some of the manipulations with the infinite sums, at one point I need that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ({\alpha^*}^{n-1} \alpha^{n-1} - {\alpha^*}^n \alpha^n) = 1$, which is a bit shady. This can probably be fixed if you do the calculation cleverer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jan suggests, there's a typo in the definition of $f$. It should read
$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} & (t \ge 1 - q^2)\\ 0 & (t = 0).\end{cases}
$$
Since $\alpha \alpha^* \ge 1-q^2$ (this follows from usual realization as in p. 123), this will imply that $a^*$ is an isometry. And $\alpha^* \alpha + \beta^* \beta = 1$ implies that the eigenspace of $\beta^* \beta$ for the eigenvalue $1$ is precisely the kernel of $\alpha$, which implies $a^* a + b^* b = 1$.

Morally, at $q=0$ you have the Toeplitz algebra as the 'quantum limit' of the deformation quantization of the $2$-dimensional symplectic leaves
$$
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\bar{z} \lambda & \sqrt{1-|z|^2}\lambda\\-\sqrt{1-|z|^2}\bar{\lambda}&z\bar{\lambda}\end{pmatrix} \mid |z| < 1 \right\} \quad (|\lambda|=1)
$$ 
inside $SU(2)$ together with boundary $U(1)$, and $C(SU_q(2))$ is an elaborate patching of these. The $q$-disc algebra generated by an operator $Z_q$ satisfying $\|Z_q\|=1$ and $1-Z_q^* Z_q = q^2 (1-Z_qZ_q^*)$ interpolates the Toeplitz algebra and the usual function algebra on the closed disc, but these algebras are in fact isomorphic to each other for $|q|<1$.

Comment: Hi Makoto. Thanks for your response! I understand that there’s surely a typo error in the definition of $ f $, but if we use $ f $ as defined in your response, then we have
\begin{align}
    a^{\ast} a
& = [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{\ast} \alpha)]^{\ast}
    [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{\ast} \alpha)] \\
& = [f(\alpha^{\ast} \alpha) ~ \alpha^{\ast}]
    [\alpha ~ f(\alpha^{\ast} \alpha)] \\
& = [f(\alpha^{\ast} \alpha)] (\alpha^{\ast} \alpha)
    [f(\alpha^{\ast} \alpha)] \\
& = 1,
\end{align}
which means that $ a $ is unitary. This forces $ b^{*} b $, hence $ b $, to be $ 0 $. Is this contradictory?

Comment: $\alpha$ has kernel, so the last equality doesn't hold.

Comment: Thank you, Makoto. Yes, the last equality doesn’t hold because $ 0 \in \sigma(\alpha^{\ast} \alpha) $ and $ 0 [f(0)]^{2} = 0 \neq 1 $. This doesn’t happen to $ \alpha \alpha^{\ast} $ because $ \alpha \alpha^{\ast} $ is invertible by the second relation, so $ 0 \notin \sigma(\alpha \alpha^{\ast}) $, which implies that $ t [f(t)]^{2} = 1 $ for all $ t \in \sigma(\alpha \alpha^{\ast}) $.