# Verifying Woronowicz’s proof that all $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $’s are isomorphic as $ C^{*} $-algebras, where $ -1 < q < 1 $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quantum-groups

This question is related to [one that I asked some time ago](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210556/a-question-on-an-argument-in-woronowicz-s-paper-on-the-compact-quantum-group).

---

> **Definition 1.** Let $ q \in (-1,1) $. Let $ A $ be a unital $ C^{*} $-algebra and $ (x,y) $ a pair of elements of $ A $. Then define the **$ q $-relations** for $ (x,y) $ to be the following five relations:
>   \begin{align}
> x^{*} x + y^{*} y       & = 1_{A}. \\
> x x^{*} + q^{2} y y^{*} & = 1_{A}. \\
> y^{*} y                 & = y y^{*}. \\
> x y                     & = q y x. \\
> x y^{*}                 & = q y^{*} x.
> \end{align}
>
> **Definition 2.** The compact quantum group $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $ is defined as the universal unital $ C^{*} $-algebra that is generated by a pair $ (x,y) $ of elements satisfying the $ q $-relations. We shall call $ (x,y) $ ‘a generating pair for $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $’.

Woronowicz’s proof that all the $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $’s are isomorphic as $ C^{*} $-algebras (contained in his paper [*Twisted $ \text{SU}(2) $ Group. An Example of a Non-Commutative Differential Calculus*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ems-ph.org%2Fjournals%2Fshow_pdf.php%3Fissn%3D0034-5318%26vol%3D23%26iss%3D1%26rank%3D5&ei=NZWTVcOoBM71oASw_ILoCg&usg=AFQjCNE7msZDaxPfyjZWHn7ajMPtH6ILag&sig2=KWZzMsTHNwfzdhb5qtZ_qQ&bvm=bv.96952980,d.cGU)) goes as follows:

1. Let $ q \in (-1,1) $.
2. Let $ (a,b) $ and $ (\alpha,\beta) $ be generating pairs for $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $ and $ {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) $ respectively.
3. The pair (of elements of $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $)
   $$
   \phi_{(a,b)} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} (a ~ f(a^{*} a),b ~ g(b^{*} b)),
   $$
   obtained via the continuous functional calculus, satisfies the $ 0 $-relations, where $ f,g \in C([0,1]) $ and have the following properties:
   $$
   f(t) =
   \begin{cases}
   0                   & \text{if $ t = 0 $}, \\
   \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}} & \text{if $ t \in \left[ 1 - q^{2},1 \right] $};
   \end{cases}
   \qquad
   g(t) =
   \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{if $ t \in \left[ 0,q^{2} \right] $}, \\
   1 & \text{if $ t = 1 $}.
   \end{cases}
   $$
   Then by the universal property of $ {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) $, there exists a unique morphism $ \Phi: {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) \to {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $ such that $ (\Phi(\alpha),\Phi(\beta)) = \phi_{(a,b)} $.
4. The pair (of elements of $ {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) $)
   $$
   \psi_{(\alpha,\beta)} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
   \left(
   \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sqrt{1 - q^{2 n}}
   \left[ (\alpha^{*})^{n - 1} \alpha^{n} - (\alpha^{*})^{n} \alpha^{n + 1} \right],
   \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} q^{n} (\alpha^{*})^{n} \beta \alpha^{n}
   \right)
   $$
   satisfies the $ q $-relations. Then by the universal property of $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) $, there exists a unique morphism $ \Psi: {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) \to {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) $ such that $ (\Psi(a),\Psi(b)) = \psi_{(\alpha,\beta)} $.
5. As $ \Phi \circ \Psi = \text{Id}_{{\text{SU}_{q}}(2)} $ and $ \Psi \circ \Phi = \text{Id}_{{\text{SU}_{0}}(2)} $, one can conclude that $ {\text{SU}_{q}}(2) \cong {\text{SU}_{0}}(2) $.

Step 3 is easily verified via routine continuous functional calculus (the linked post says more about this).

Steps 4 and 5 appear very difficult. I have absolutely no idea how Woronowicz obtained the infinite series in Step 4, but I am very sure that he could not have guessed them. I would therefore like to ask:

> **Question 1.** How can we derive the infinite series in Step 4 and prove that the pair $ \psi_{(\alpha,\beta)} $ satisfies the $ q $-relations? I believe that once this is answered, Step 5 can be tackled.

I must also mention that Woronowicz claims the following identity:
$$
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sqrt{1 - q^{2 n}}
  \left[ (\alpha^{*})^{n - 1} \alpha^{n} - (\alpha^{*})^{n} \alpha^{n + 1} \right]
= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
  \frac{\left( 1 - q^{2} \right) q^{2 n}}{\sqrt{1 - q^{2 n}} + \sqrt{1 - q^{2 (n + 1)}}}
  (\alpha^{*})^{n} \alpha^{n + 1}.
$$
The infinite series on the right is readily seen to be absolutely convergent. I could easily verify that
\begin{align}
\forall N \in \Bbb{N}: \qquad
  & ~ \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sqrt{1 - q^{2 n}}
      \left[ (\alpha^{*})^{n - 1} \alpha^{n} - (\alpha^{*})^{n} \alpha^{n + 1} \right] \\
= & ~ \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1}
      \frac{\left( 1 - q^{2} \right) q^{2 n}}{\sqrt{1 - q^{2 n}} + \sqrt{1 - q^{2 (n + 1)}}}
      (\alpha^{*})^{n} \alpha^{n + 1} -
      \sqrt{1 - q^{2 N}} (\alpha^{*})^{N} \alpha^{N + 1},
\end{align}
but I was unable to prove that $ \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \sqrt{1 - q^{2 N}} (\alpha^{*})^{N} \alpha^{N + 1} = 0_{{\text{SU}_{0}}(2)} $.

> **Question 2.** How can we prove that $ \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \sqrt{1 - q^{2 N}} (\alpha^{*})^{N} \alpha^{N + 1} = 0_{{\text{SU}_{0}}(2)} $?

These are all the questions that I have. Thank you very much for your help!